# mingw32 set command do not work

Tags: mingw, bitcoin

I am trying to build a bitcoin. I follow this tutorial https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=149479.0 Everythink work good (I think) but I stop on step 2.7 This command do not work for me:

```
set INCLUDE=C:\deps\libpng-1.6.8;C:\deps\openssl-1.0.1e\include
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** I read through your link again, and the issue is due to the instructions being built for Windows command line, not cygwin. From standard `cmd`, the unquoted original works just fine. If doing so in cygwin, however, you must quote the value *and* remove `set`:

```
INCLUDE="C:\deps\libpng-1.6.8;C:\deps\openssl-1.0.1e\include"
```

In Windows `cmd`:

```
c:\>set INCLUDE=C:\deps\libpng-1.6.8;C:\deps\openssl-1.0.1e\include

c:\>echo %INCLUDE%
C:\deps\libpng-1.6.8;C:\deps\openssl-1.0.1e\include
```

...in cygwin:

```
[user@machine /]> INCLUDE="C:\deps\libpng-1.6.8;C:\deps\openssl-1.0.1e\include"
[user@machine /]> echo $INCLUDE
C:\deps\libpng-1.6.8;C:\deps\openssl-1.0.1e\include
```

I am unsure if the full directions, as written on that page, work via cygwin, so you may want to just do it all from the Windows command prompt.